# Bash function to "use" the most recent "dated" file in a dir

Tags: bash, function, date, filenames

I have a dir with a crap load (hundreds) of log files from over time. In certain cases I want to make a note regarding the most recent (by date in filename, not by creation time) log or I just need some piece of info from it and i want to view it quickly and I just know it was (usually) the last one created (but always) with the newest date. So I wanted to make a "simple" function in my bashrc to overcome this problem, basically what I want is a function that goes to a specific dir and finds the latest log by date (always in the same format) and open it with less or whatever pager I want.

The logs are formatted like this:
typeoflog-short-description-$(date "+%-m-%-d-%y")
basically the digits in between the last 3 dashes are what I'm interested in, for example(s):

update-log-2-24-18

removed-cuda-opencl-nvidia-12-2-19

whatever-changes-1-18-19

Now if it was January, 20 2019 and this was the last log added to the dir I need a way to see what the highest number is in the last 2 digits of the filename (that i don't really have a problem with), then check for the highest month that would be 2 "dashes" from the last set of digits whether it be 2 digits or 1 for the month, and then do the same thing for the day of the month and set that as a local variable and use it like the following example.

Something like this:

```
viewlatestlog(){
    local loc="~/.logdir"
    local name=$(echo $loc/*-19 | #awk or cut or sort or i could even loop it from 1-31 and 1-12 for the days and months.)
    #I have ideas, but i know there has to be a better way to do this and it's not coming to me, maybe with expr or a couple of sort commands; i'm not sure, it would have been easier if i had made is so that each date number had 2 digits always... But I didn't
    ## But the ultimate goal is that i can run something like this command at the end
    less $loc/$name
{
```

PS. For bonus points you could also tell me if there is a way to automatically copy the filename (with the location and all or without, I don't really care) to my linux clipboard, so when I'm making my note I can "link" to the log file if I ever need to go back to it...

Edit: Cleaned up post a little bit, I tend to my questions way too wordy, I apologize.

Comment: Consider replacing the long story with short question that clarifies - (1) what is your file format (show few file names, so it's possible to test), and (2) the expected output.

Comment: you should consider changing your log-format into `logfile-YYYY-MM-DD`, this is a text-sortable format.

Comment: When you want to use `zsh` instead of bash, you can use the glob `logfile*(.om[1])`. This will give you the file with the latest modification time.

Comment: I now think that @kvantour is probably right... I just never liked the way my filenames looked with that format. But now I'm wishing I would have used that instead.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `sort` can sort by fields:

```
$ find . -name whatever-changes-\* | sort -n -t- -k5 -k3 -k4
./whatever-changes-3-01-18
./whatever-changes-1-18-19
./whatever-changes-2-12-19
./whatever-changes-11-01-19
```

The option `-t` specifies the field delimiter and the option `-k` selects the fields starting with 1. The option `-n` specifies numeric sort.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames do not contain tabs or newlines, how about:

```
loc="~/.logdir"
for f in "$loc"/* ; do
    if [[ $f =~ -([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{2})$ ]]; then
        mm=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        dd=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        yy=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        printf "%02d%02d%02d\t%s\n" "$yy" "$mm" "$dd" "$f"
    fi
done | sort -r | head -n 1 | cut -f 2
```

- First extract the month, date, and year from the filename.
- Then create a date string formatted as "YYMMDD" and prepend to the
  filename delimited by a tab character.
- Then you can perform the `sort` command on the list.
- Finally you can obtain the desired (latest) filename by extracting with `top` and `cut`.

Hope this helps.